# Regarding early church "Commentary of Matthew" by Origen, should Christians trust Matthew was the first Gospel written in Hebrew?

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, bible-commentary, origen

Until reading the "Commentary on the Gospel of Matthew" by Origen Adamantius, I presumed (based on the teachings of Wikipedia) that the original manuscript of Matthew was written in Greek & that Mark was the earliest gospel.

**In contrast to internet, early church scholars like Origen (around 246-248 AD) stated that the Gospel of Matthew was written in Hebrew & that Mark was the second gospel account written.**

> Concerning the four Gospels which alone are uncontroverted in the Church of God under heaven, I have learned by tradition that the Gospel according to Matthew, who was at one time a publican and afterwards an Apostle of Jesus Christ, was written first; and that he composed it in the Hebrew tongue and published it for the converts from Judaism. The second written was that according to Mark, who wrote it according to the instruction of Peter, who, in his General Epistle, acknowledged him as a son, saying, "The church that is in Babylon, elect together with you, saluteth you; and so doth Mark my son." [5151] And third, was that according to Luke, the Gospel commended by [5152] Paul, which he composed for the converts from the Gentiles. Last of all, that according to John.

[Biblehub - Origen's Commentary on Matthew's Gospel](https://biblehub.com/library/origen/origens_commentary_on_the_gospel_of_matthew/from_the_first_book_of.htm)

**Regarding early church "Commentary of Matthew" by Origen, should Christians trust Matthew was the first Gospel written in Hebrew?**

Comment: No Hebrew manuscript has ever been found to support this hypothesis.

Comment: As if those scholars were blissfully unaware of the pious traditions about Matthew's Gospel...

Comment: Edited only to demonstrate linking. Please feel free to rollback if you wish.